# web-mode no syntax or color formatting with css and scss?

Tags: web-mode

New user of vanilla Emacs 28.1 here, I just installed `web-mode` and it works great so far except for CSS and SASS / SCSS files. With those, `web-mode` doesn't provide any syntax highlighting or colorizing. These are my settings:

```
(setq web-mode-enable-css-colorization t
      web-mode-enable-front-matter-block t
      web-mode-engines-alist
      '(("liquid" . "\\.html\\'")
        ("liquid" . "\\.xml\\'")))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.css\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sass\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.xml\\'" . web-mode))
```

Also tried to assign CSS / SCSS engines to CSS / SASS / SCSS files but no luck there.

Giving `M-x web-mode-set-content-type` CSS or SCSS didn't work either.

Trying different themes also didn't change anything.

All tested files are fine with `css-mode` and `scss-mode`.

Any idea what I could do to fix this?

Thank you :)

[image: SASS with scss-mode]
[image: SASS with web-mode]

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

> except for CSS and SASS / SCSS files

Don't use `web-mode` for those files.

Emacs has good support for CSS and (in recent versions) SCSS files by default, so there's no reason to tell it to do anything different.

I can't help you with that semantic-indentation SASS format, though. (*Personally* I'd want to use SCSS syntax regardless of Emacs support, but maybe there's something which will deal with that.)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I use web-mode with *.css and *.scss files and I get syntax highlighting there. But I get no syntax highlighting for *.sass files. I do get syntax highlighting for sass inside html, using `<style lang="sass">`. And web-mode source code shows it supports sass. So I think it is just not recognizing *.sass files correctly.

I got syntax highlighting in *.sass files to work by adding:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.sass\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'web-mode-content-types
             '("sass" . "\\.sass\\'"))
```

You already have the first of these. And you tried M-x web-mode-set-content-type, which worked for me, but only for the current buffer.

Comment: Odd! Also: it's interesting that the `---` and `a` and `blockquote` are getting highlighted, but nothing else is.

Comment: I tested it again and it highlights my `---` and also `a` and `blockquote`. But unlike your screenshot, mine also highlights `color:` and `font-size:` etc. in the web-mode-css-property-name-face. Sadly I don't know why yours doesn't.